# How can I tell the compiler to use my overloaded operator instead of using the "normal" operator?

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

Here I have the enum class:

```
enum class wahl {
   schere  , stein  , papier 
};
```

And then I overload the operator < and >

```
bool operator<(wahl &wahl1, wahl &wahl2) {
  switch (wahl1) {
    case wahl::papier: {
        if (wahl2 == wahl::schere) {
            return true; break;
        } //papier < schere
        else if (wahl2 == wahl::stein) {
            return false; break;
        } //papier > stein
        else {
            return false; break;
        }
    }
    case wahl::schere: {
        if (wahl2 == wahl::stein) {
            return true; break;
        } //schere < stein
        else if (wahl2 == wahl::papier) {
            return false; break;
        } //schere > papier
        else {
            return false; break;
        }
    }
    case wahl::stein: {
        if (wahl2 == wahl::papier) {
            return true; break;
        } //stein < papier
        else if (wahl2 == wahl::schere) {
            return false; break;
        } //stein > schere
        else {
            return false; break;
        }
     }
  }
};

bool operator > (const wahl wahl1, const wahl wahl2) {
switch (wahl1) {
case wahl::papier: {
    if (wahl2 == wahl::schere) {
        return false; break;
    }
    // papier < schere
    else if (wahl2 == wahl::stein) {
        return true; break;
    } //papier > stein
    else {
        return false; break;
    }
}
case wahl::schere: {
    if (wahl2 == wahl::stein) {
        return false; break;
    } //schere < stein
    else if (wahl2 == wahl::papier) {
        return true; break;
    } //schere > papier
    else {
        return false; break;
    }
}
case wahl::stein: {
    if (wahl2 == wahl::papier) {
        return false; break;
    } //stein < papier
    else if (wahl2 == wahl::schere) {
        return true; break;
    } //stein > schere
    else {
        return false; break;

    }
}
}
};
```

I have another class, named player :

```
class player {
wahl pl_wahl;
int pl_score;
char* pl_name;

public:

player() {}
player(int score, wahl wahl, char* name) : 
    pl_wahl{ wahl }, pl_score{ score }, pl_name{ name } {}

wahl pl_get_wahl() {
    return pl_wahl;
}

char* pl_get_name() {
    return pl_name;
}

int &pl_get_score() {
    return pl_score;
}
};
```

And here where I used the comparator :

```
class game {

player game_player1, game_player2, game_momentan_gewinner;
int game_score_max;

public:
game() {}
game(player player1, player player2, int score_max) : 
    game_player1{player1},
    game_player2{player2},
    game_score_max{ score_max } {}

void vergleichen() {
    if (game_player1.pl_get_wahl() > game_player2.pl_get_wahl()) {
        game_momentan_gewinner = game_player1;
        std::cout << "Gewinner dieser Runde ist Player 1 : " <<
            game_momentan_gewinner.pl_get_name() << std::endl;
    }
    if (game_player1.pl_get_wahl() < game_player2.pl_get_wahl()) {
        game_momentan_gewinner = game_player2;
        std::cout << "Gewinner dieser Runde ist Player 2 : " <<
            game_momentan_gewinner.pl_get_name() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Remis" << std::endl;
    }

}
};
```

The problem that I have, is enum will be proceed as int. And if I ask the compare two enum variables, the result will depend on the int value rather than taking the value, that I have set with the overloaded operator.

Is there any way, that i can stop the compiler to use the int value of the enum variables, and compare the enum variables in the way I want like in the overloaded operator?

Comment: You probably want `bool operator<(const wahl &wahl1, const wahl &wahl2)` or `bool operator<(wahl wahl1, wahl wahl2)`.

Comment: Are you using lvalues when you try to compare them?  Maybe your operator should not take references.

Comment: BTW, care, as you operator doesn't respect strict ordering, and so you should not use it in some places (as in `std::sort(wahls.begin(), wahls.end())` or `std::map<wahl, T>`).

Comment: Your example [doesn't even compile](https://ideone.com/IOUR6O).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You *added code that isn't in the question* which doesn't compile.

Comment: It's an enum, you choose value order, have you considered listing them in the order that you want them to compare in?

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks but the result is still the same

Comment: @JonathanMee Hint: schere, stein, papier translates to scissors, rock, paper.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes it is not the whole code. all i want to do is to compare two enum variables. `if ( wahl::papier > wahl::schere)`. It should be false, since schere > papier. But it comes out true. Assuming that enum will be processed as an integer, then it is true that papier>schere

Comment: @JonathanMee should have mentioned that earlier. Thanks

Comment: @ptd You're using the `>` operator there. You say in your question that you implemented both `<` and `>`, but you only show the code for `<`. If you actually only implemented `operator<`, it makes sense that it doesn't work when you test with `>`.

Comment: @hvd I add both, but I hesitate to upload the whole code because it will be too long and repetitive.

Comment: @ptd In that case, can you edit your question to include what you tried (what Jarod42 suggested), along with a simple function that uses the `<` operator that doesn't work the way you expect it to? At least with the `operator<(wahl wahl1, wahl wahl2)` version, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @hvd edited :))

Comment: Thanks, it's not really what I meant, I meant a simple function that doesn't need the rest of your program, a simple function just to demonstrate how `<` and `>` don't behave the way you like. But... you're saying that `game_player1.pl_get_wahl() > game_player2.pl_get_wahl()` doesn't call your `operator>`, even if it's declared as `bool operator > (const wahl wahl1, const wahl wahl2)` like it is in your question? That doesn't sound right. And that's something that should be easy to reproduce in a stand-alone function if that's really what's happening.

Comment: @hvd if i move my mouse pointer around the < and > it will show me the declaration `bool operator > (const bla bla bla ` but if I place a break point and try to follow step by step, the compiler still doesn't know that schere>papier. That's why I assume that the compiler still takes the int value. Or is there any other possibilities?

Comment: No, that sounds about right. If the debugger doesn't go to your custom function, it's almost certainly not being called. You could as a sanity check insert some debug print statements, but I wouldn't expect them to print anything. With that declaration, it *should* be called though, and if I try it myself in a simple test program that simply does `std::cout << (wahl::schere > wahl::papier) << '\n';`, I find that it *does* get called (it prints `1`), which is why I'm fairly certain there's relevant info still missing. If you create a function that just does that, nothing else, what happens?

Comment: Note on improving the code: having `break;` after a `return` statement makes no sense; it’s never reached.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes thank you

Comment: @hvd the code works on xcode, only when I overload the function before I declare the class game. But when I try to do that on visual studio, I get the error : operator < is ambigous. The same thing with operator >

Comment: @hvd works also with dev c++ with same condition like in xcode. But can't get it works on visual studio

Answer (score 0):

If you use correct signature, it should be ok:

```
bool operator<(wahl lhs, wahl rhs);
bool operator>(wahl lhs, wahl rhs);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/U2XXt8)